# site is moveable in ipad

Tags: ipad, css, responsive-design

I think it's css problem. my site is moveable by left and right gesture on ipad. It cause the right most border doesn't apply to `width : 100%`

It work perfectly when I use responsive inspector for ipad view in PC, but not in actual ipad.

Comment: Do you mean the border is _added_ to the 100% width? Try adding `box-sizing: border-box;`.  That will mean the 100% width includes the border.

Comment: @davidpauljunior I'm already using bootstrap

Comment: You need to provide more information then.  How can we help with that question?  There's no code, no link, just a vague description.

Comment: @davidpauljunior do you have an ipad?

Comment: Yeah.  But you're still going to need to add more to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this metatag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,maximum-scale=1.0" />
```